# django: hyperlink in dict to html templates as hyperlink

Tags: django, django-templates

I have dict with hyderlink, example :

```
data = [{a:<\a href="http://someexample.com/a">a</a>,
        b:'<\a href="http://someexample.com/b">b</a>'}]
```

Note : here i have add ***/a href*** because stack overflow takes it has hyperlink

if i want to output this in html , it displays a normal html text instead of hyperlink

template

```
<table>
{% for fetch in data %}
<tr>
<td>{{ fetch.a }}</td>
<td>{{ fetch.b }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

it gives output like html text instead of hyperlink

1. <\a href="http://someexample.com/a">a
2. <\a href="http://someexample.com/b">b

any help it really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the entire anchor tag, you should be storing just the URL (using URLField if you're storing it in a model), and then include it in your template as follows:

```
<table>
    {% for fetch in data %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ fetch.a }}">{{ fetch.a }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ fetch.b }}">{{ fetch.b }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of [automatic string escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping) in the template engine. You can prevent escaping with the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter, like:

```
<table>
{% for fetch in data %}
<tr>
<td>{{ fetch.a|safe }}</td>
<td>{{ fetch.b|safe }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```